# Using <name> = ... Does not name a type

Tags: c++, templates, using

The goal is to define a function in a template object with void (void) as prototype.
The following code:

```
template <class T>
using ClassVoidFunctionPointer = void (T::*)(void);

class Scheduler {

public:
        Scheduler(void);
        ~Scheduler(void);
        template <class T>
        void addTask(unsigned short interval, unsigned short delay,T templateClass,ClassVoidFunctionPointer classFunctionPtr );//For newer functions
...
}
```

This gives me errors:

```
inc/scheduler.h:18:77: error: 'ClassVoidFunctionPointer' is not a type
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: `ClassVoidFunctionPointer` is not a type. It is a template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot template arguments:

```
, ClassVoidFunctionPointer<T> classFunctionPtr,
```